# Do enemies respawn indefinitely in target escort missions?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Enemies spawn seemingly every round on [target escort](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Target_Escort) missions. Can I hang back and take care of them completely before proceeding, or will I end up fighting until they eventually overpower my troops?

Comment: Worth noting: enemies spawn based on your VIP's distance from the exit. If you don't move the VIP, no new enemies will spawn. This lets you clean up each wave and position your troops for the next one, then start gradually moving forward until you activate it.

Comment: @ChrisHayes So does that mean the total number of enemies will depend on how many times your vip moves?

Comment: @Benubird There are set trigger locations on the map that cause a wave to spawn once the VIP is within those triggers. I don't think any of the triggers are avoidable on escort missions, so the number of enemies you fight is always fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There are a finite number of enemies.**

The Target Extraction missions always end with the objective, "eliminate any remaining hostiles," unless you've already killed them all.

You can also move your squad into the extraction zone after the VIP and end the mission that way. However, you won't get your loot and any XCOM personnel outside the zone when you end the mission are lost.

[XCOM wiki](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Target_Extraction)